# How to create a popup alert with sound in asp.net website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, popupwindow

I'm a college student creating a farm animal tracking application that tracks animals using RFID.

My problem is that when an animal leaves the perimeter a stored procedure is executed that removes the animal from that table and logs it in another.

I want the application to show a popup message and trigger an alert that this has happened.
I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 for my database server and Visual Studio 2012.

How can this be done?

Comment: I tried using javascript to do the popup message but its not going well. I'm very new to this thing. i just want to do this for my project.

Comment: Have you looked at using WebSockets and Socket.IO?

Comment: @Jon No i havnt thought about that. This project is just for my final year. we dont even have the rfid readers and tags. Its just simulating what would happen. all i want is to alarm and popup to alert the farm

Comment: @Sheldon Still you have to deal with the problem that the client doesn't know when an animal is outside of the perimiter. You can accomplish this in two ways. The server could notify the client via a WebSocket (Socket.IO is one of the more popular solutions.), or the client could make a request to the server every few seconds and the server would respond with the animal that has moved out of the perimeter.

I think the last option would be the easiest way for you to accomplish this goal.

Comment: ok @Jon. could you point me in the right direction then.. that would be great.

Comment: @Sheldon You'll need to create a REST API and poll it with HTTP requests from the client. Google around, you'll find the answers.

Comment: @Jon ok im working on it. thanks very much.